# How to create Unit Testing for filterPredicate function of Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-material, jasmine

I am new on AUT and working on this for a week but it seems like my test can't cover the whole function.

**Component**

```
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
export class AppComponent {
 dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<UserData>([]);
 ...
}
```

**Function**

```
setupfilter(column: string) :void {
 this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter: string): boolean => {
  return (
   data[column].toString().toLowerCase().includes(filter)
  );
 }
}
```

**Test**

```
    let app : AppComponent;
    ...
    it('should call setupfilter() on search',()=>{
    
      let spy1 = spyOn(app, 'setupfilter');
      let spy2 = spyOn(app.dataSource, 'filterPredicate');
    
      app.setupfilter('firstname');
    
      expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(spy2).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(app.dataSource.filterPredicate.length).toBeGreaterThan(1);
    });
```

Comment: What's `app`? Is it a service class? And `dataSource`. Show the complete, minimal code.

Comment: @slideshowp2 Hi, I already edited my question please check.